# What is the difference between rendered and apex: actionRegion

Tags: visualforce, rerender

What is the difference between rendered and apex:actionRegion? Please provide me with an  example of the difference.

Comment: Anu, assuming that you've read the documentation, what precisely are you confused about ?

Comment: Can you let us know exactly what you're after here? It's difficult to tell.

Comment: I have used both apex:actionRegion and rendered according to the requirement on VF page. But i today in an interview i have this question. So just want to know how to explain to the interviewer.

Answer (score 1):

`<apex:actionRegion>` tags are a way to group form controls such that only input fields etc. contained within them are sent back to the controller when an action inside them is fired.

"rendered" is a parameter on many Visualforce tags that controls the visibility of the element based on some condition.

As you can see they're totally different things so I think you might need to clarify your question a little!